# FlowType annotation for a parameter that must be a Class

Tags: javascript, class, flowtype

I'm using Flow to declare typing on a React project. In this project, I have a function that intantiantes/builds services so they can be used by reducers. The only constraint on these services that are provided to my build function is they must be a Class. That is, they must be able to be instantiated by using `new`.

My best solution (which isn't a solution) is to use `mixed` as the type and add runtime checks. Does anyone know how this can be statically type checked?

I'm using Flow 0.61.0. Here's a basic example of my dilemma.

```js
// @flow

function buildService(
  Service: ???, 
  dependencies: {[string]: {}|Function} = {}
) {
    return new Service(dependencies)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the special [`Class<T>`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-class) utility type.

```
// @flow

function buildService<T: {}>(
  Service: Class<T>,
  dependencies: {[string]: {}|Function} = {}
): T {
    return new Service(dependencies)
}
```